# AFNetworking can not access setAuthenticationChallengeBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have installed

```
pod 'AFNetworking'
```

And added to header

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFURLConnectionOperation.h"
```

But I got error

> No visible @interface for 'AFURLConnectionOperation' declares the
>   selector setAuthenticationChallengeBlock

Code used

```
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someURL"]];
AFURLConnectionOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest];

    [operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge)
    {
        if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0)
        {
            NSURLCredential *creds = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"USERNAME"
                                                                password:@"PASSWORD"
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

            [[challenge sender] useCredential:creds forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Previous auth challenge failed. Are username and password correct?");
        }
    }];
```

Comment: BTW, don't forget to call `cancelAuthenticationChallenge` in your else clause.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant to use [`setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock%3a):

```
[operation setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *creds = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"USERNAME"
                                                            password:@"PASSWORD"
                                                         persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

        [[challenge sender] useCredential:creds forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Previous auth challenge failed. Are username and password correct?");
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}];
```

Also, make sure that all paths of execution call one of the [`NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods (e.g., above, I call `cancelAuthenticationChallenge:` if the authentication failed).